# How does Chai JS make function parentheses optional?

Tags: javascript, function, chai, method-chaining

I'm referring to the testing assertion library : http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#false

You can write language chain assertions like the following:

```
expect(false).to.be.false;
```

expect() is obviously a global function, "to.be" looks like two properties, but how does the last part "false" work. I'm expecting that it would have to be a function call:

```
expect(false).to.be.false();
```

Is this 2015 ES syntax? I can't seem to find a reference to it in https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features

Stack Overflow says its not possible: [How to implement optional parentheses during function call? (function overloading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761069/how-to-implement-optional-parentheses-during-function-call-function-overloadin)

Can anyone shed some light on how something like this is implemented ?

Source Code: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L281

Comment: Learn about `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this (and a lot of other stuff) with `Object.defineProperty`. Here's a basic example:

```
// our "constructor" takes some value we want to test
var Test = function (value) {
    // create our object
    var testObj = {};

    // give it a property called "false"
    Object.defineProperty(testObj, 'false', {
        // the "get" function decides what is returned
        // when the `false` property is retrieved
        get: function () {
            return !value;
        }
    });
    // return our object
    return testObj;
};

var f1 = Test(false);
console.log(f1.false); // true
var f2 = Test("other");
console.log(f2.false); // false
```

There's a lot more you can do with `Object.defineProperty`. You should check out [the MDN docs for `Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for detail.